# Redirect/Forward from a servlet with PrettyFaces

Tags: jsf, servlets, prettyfaces

i am using PrettyFaces 3.3.0
and i want to make custom redirect and forward from a servlet

i found the following code on their documentation:

```
public class CustomRedirector 
{
    public void redirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                            String mappingId, Map<String, String[]>params)
    {
        PrettyContext context = PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance(request);
        PrettyURLBuilder builder = new PrettyURLBuilder();

        URLMapping mapping = context.getConfig().getMappingById(mappingId);
        String targetURL = builder.build(mapping, params);

        targetURL = response.encodeRedirectURL(targetURL);
        response.sendRedirect(targetURL);
    }       
}
```

and i was wondering how to call the redirect method from the servlet, what will be the mappingId (the requestURI ?) and what will be the value of `Map<String, String[]>params`, i need a small example please of calling above method from a servlet?

and how to do forwarding from servlet with prettyfaces too, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "String mappingId" is the ID of the url-mapping in your PrettyFaces configuration. Each url-mapping should have an ID (either in the XML, or the Annotations configuration.)

The Map params is a list of parameters in name-value pairs that is used to generate the outbound link based on the URL-mapping pattern specified by the id.

For example:

```
<url-mapping id="foo">
    <pattern value="/#{cat}/#{item}" />
    <view-id value="/bar.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

So you would call your method like so:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("cat", "blah");
map.put("item", "45");
new CustomRedirector.redirect(request, response, "foo", map);
```

And you will be redirected to:

```
/blah/45
```